# KeyboardAwareScrollView props innerRef scrollToEnd not working

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm trying to call scrollToEnd() in a screen that uses https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view and I get the error:

> "cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

My code looks like this:

> let scroll

(at the beginning of the file)

Then, inside the return:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView innerRef={ref => { scroll = ref }}>
my scrollable code
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

And then there is a button which has

> onPress={() => scroll.props.scrolltoEnd()}

Clicking the button gives the error above, which makes me think I'm not using innerRef correctly? Do I need to use useRef instead at some point? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You must use innerRef instead of ref and it will work.

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
      innerRef={(ref) => {
        scrollRef.current = ref;
      }}
```

Answer (score 1):

on KeyboardAwareScrollView use React.useRef

```
 const scrollRef = React.useRef(null);


 <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      ref={scrollRef}
      ....
```

And on your input, listen onContentSizeChange

```
 <Input

 onContentSizeChange={(e) => {
                if (scrollRef && scrollRef.current) {
                  scrollRef.current?.scrollToEnd();
                }
              }}
 />
```

Comment: `scrollRef` is always null, I cannot find a way to scroll to bottom of  KeyboardAwareScrollView

Answer (score 0):

```
// use focussed hook 
     const isFocused = useIsFocused();    

// declare useref 
     const scrollViewRef = useRef<KeyboardAwareScrollView | null>(null);
    
// This will scroll the view (to top x:0, y:0, animated:true), every time view is focussed

     useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollToPosition) {
          scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollToPosition(0, 0, true);
        }
      }, [isFocused]);
    
// Assigning ref
     <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref={ref => { scrollViewRef.current = ref }}> Your content </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.